# Android: refreshing list view from different activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, refresh

I have ListActivity with CustomArrayAdapter. My extension of ArrayAdapter allows me to do add/remove operations with the rows. It works fine...inside ListActivity. But then I need to add/edit rows in my list from different Activity and troubles begin. How can I do that? All I need inside my EditActivity is CustomArrayAdapter object. I made it static and tried. It worked, but is it a right thing?
Thanks for the answers, masters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What comes in my mind:

- One way could be to make your objects in the ArrayList `serializable` you could pass then  the actual list to the next activity via intent and use it there for the adapter.
- Other way would be: if you know the ID of the element which you want to delete, pass it as intent, delete it from the ArrayList and set `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

I don't think to have a static ArrayAdapter class is the right way. This means you affect both activities at the same time. Because none of them have an own object.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah. I got it. Just sturt the other activity for fesult and pass new/modified object back. Thanks!

Comment: @Nick you're welcome ;) Would be good if you accept the answer. So the next one can see it.

Comment: @Nick no problem, that's why I'm telling you ;) +1 also for you :)